# Homomorphism of Polynomial Domains induced by a homomorphism of the ring of coefficients (G7)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 24, G7.

> Let $h:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n$ be a homomorphism with kernel $K$.
>   Define $\bar{h}: \mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ by
>
> $\quad\bar{h}(a_0 + a_1x +\cdots a_nx^n) = h(a_0) + h(a_1)x +\cdots +h(a_n)x^n$
>
> Let $n$ be a prime.
>   Prove that if $a(x)b(x)\in \operatorname{ker}\bar{h}$, then either $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ is in
>   $\operatorname{ker}\bar{h}$.

Attempt:

1. Given $n$ is a prime, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an integral domain, for if $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ and
   $ab\equiv 0\,(\operatorname{mod}n)$, then $n$ necessarily divides either $a$ or $b$.
2. $a(x)b(x)\in\operatorname{ker}\bar{h}$ implies $\bar{h}(a(x)b(x))=0$.
3. $h$ being a ring homomorphism implies $\bar{h}$ is a ring homomorphism. Hence,$\bar{h}\left(a(x)b(x)\right)=\bar{h}\left(a(x)\right)\bar{h}\left(b(x)\right) = 0$.
4. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an integral domain implies $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ is an integral domain.  Hence either $\bar{h}\left(a(x)\right)$ or $\bar{h}\left(b(x)\right)$ must be zero; and therefore either $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ is in $\operatorname{ker}\bar{h}$.

Correct?

Comment: Sure it is correct. In general when you have a ring homomorphism between R and a integral domain S, then Its kernel is always a prime ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof works, as long as you prove that $\bar h$ is a homomorphism itself(you have not written the details, only said you have to use the fact that $h$ is a homomorphism : but if you are confident on this, then it is ok).

In more generality, you have proved one part of the statement : "Given $\phi :R \to S$, a ring homomorphism between $R$ and an integral domain $S$, the kernel of $\phi$ is always a prime ideal of $R$". Once you prove that it is closed under addition, which is a similar proof, the kernel is shown to be a prime ideal.

Comment: Thanks!  I've added a proof that $\bar{h}$ is a homomorphism at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529553/homomorphism-of-polynomial-domains-induced-by-a-homomorphism-of-the-ring-of-coef

Comment: Great , thanks for that