# Homomorphism of Polynomial Domains induced by a homomorphism of the ring of coefficients (G1)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 24, G1.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be rings and let $h: A\rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism with kernel $K$. 
>   Define $\bar{h}: A[x]\rightarrow B[x]$ by
>
> $\quad\bar{h}(a_0 + a_1x +\cdots a_nx^n) = h(a_0) + h(a_1)x +\cdots +h(a_n)x^n$
>
> Prove that $\bar{h}$ is a homomorphism from $A[x]$ to $B[x]$.

Attempt:

Let $a(x), b(x)\in A[x]$, where $\operatorname{deg} a(x)=n, \operatorname{deg} b(x)=m$
and $m\le n$.
\begin{align*}
    \bar{h}(a(x) + b(x)) &= \bar{h}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k + \sum_{k=0}^m b_kx^k\right) \\
    &= \bar{h}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (a_k+b_k) x^k\right) \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^n h(a_k+b_k) x^k \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^n \left(h(a_k) + h(b_k)\right) x^k & \text{by homomorphism of }h \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^n h(a_k)x^k + \sum_{k=0}^m h(b_k)x^k \\
    &= \bar{h}(a(x)) + \bar{h}(b(x))
\end{align*}
Hence $\bar{h}$ is a homomorphism over addition from $A[x]$ to $B[x]$.

\begin{align*}
    \bar{h}(a(x)b(x)) &= \bar{h}\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^m b_kx^k\right)\right) \\
&= \bar{h}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\left(\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j\right)x^k\right) \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}h\left(\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j\right)x^k \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\left(\sum_{i+j=k}h(a_ib_j)\right)x^k & \text{by homomorphism of }h\text{ over addition}  \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\left(\sum_{i+j=k}h(a_i)h(b_j)\right)x^k & \text{by homomorphism of }h\text{ over multiplication} \\
    &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^n h(a_k)x^k\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^m h(b_k)x^k\right) \\
    &= \bar{h}(a(x)) \bar{h}(b(x))
\end{align*}
Hence $\bar{h}$ is a ring homomorphism from $A[x]$ to $B[x]$.

Correct?

Comment: Here's an interesting post about defining polynomials over non-commutative rings: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806119/do-polynomials-make-sense-over-non-commutative-rings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ring $A$ is commutative, then everything about your proof is good.

If $A$ is not commutative, then you have to be careful about how you're defining the polynomial ring $A[x]$. If you define polynomials so that the indeterminate $x$ commutes with everything in $A$, then everything in your proof is good. If you define polynomials so that you are not assuming that $x$ commutes with everything in $A$, then you will no longer have

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^m b_kx^k\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+m}\left(\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j\right)x^k,$$

so your proof will no longer work.

**Edit:** Actually, there could potentially be one other issue. Let $A$ and $B$ be rings, and let $h:A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism. Some mathematicians define ring homomorphisms so that the definition includes the condition that $h(1_A)=1_B$, where $1_A$ is the multiplicative identity of $A$ and $1_B$ is the multiplicative identity of $B$. If this is the definition of ring homomorphism that you're using, then your proof should also show that $\bar{h}\left(1_{A[x]}\right)=1_{B[x]}$.

Comment: Interesting.  I believe commutativity of the coefficient and the indeterminate is implicitly assumed in the question, for otherwise it seems completely beyond what has been covered in Pinter's Abstract Algebra up to and including Chapter 24.  Also, I don't see the definition of ring homomorphism includes the condition that $h(1_A) = 1_B$ in that book neither.  After all, a ring in general doesn't necessarily have a unity.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the book, unfortunately. I've been looking at an online version of the book that I found here: http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jcohen/402/Pinter%20Algebra.pdf and in that chapter the author assumes that rings are commutative and have identity when he defines polynomials. If you don't assume the ring is commutative, then there are pros and cons to assuming that $x$ commutes with every element of the ring.

Comment: Some mathematicians assume that all rings have an identity, and some mathematicians don't assume this. Also, some mathematicians require that ring homomorphisms send $1\mapsto1$, and some mathematicians don't require this. When mathematicians are trying to decide which definitions to use, they typically go by whatever will be the most convenient for their research.

Comment: Do you specifically refer to the *multiplicative* identity (aka unity)?  Since a ring is also a group, by definition an additive identity always exists.

Comment: That's right. Sorry for the confusion there. All rings have an additive identity $0$, so when I was talking about whether or not rings had identities, I meant multiplicative identities. My comments would have been more clear if I said "unity" instead of "identity".